# Call a function multiple time and get all value as single list php

Tags: php, laravel, routes, symfony-routing, symfony-components

I want to call a method multiple time and get all result as single array or anything . As example laravel Web.php file

```
<?php 
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get("test",'HomeController@index');
```

I want to get result like

```
$route=[
  '/'=>'',
  'test'=>"HomeController@index"
];
```

Comment: can you elaborate your question? what do you mean by that result? is that a result in a query? etc

Comment: No sorry for my bad English. i want all get method argument as a single list

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script to get all routes keyed by their url.

```
$routes = collect(Route::getRoutes())->mapWithKeys(function ($route) {
    return [$route->uri => $route->action['uses']];
})->toArray();

dd($routes);
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer . I am using symfony routing component for learning purpose . But i think your answer is based on Laravel .